# How to disable service name starting with dash symbol "-"

Tags: linux, service, systemctl

By mistake I have created a service that is named `-server`. When i try to stop or disable it using command `sudo systemctl stop "-server"` i get error saying `Failed to parse signal string erver.` Notice that `s` letter is gone due to dash symbol before it; I think that `systemctl` interprets it as a parameter because of dash.

How do I pass service name in a way that it wont be misinterpreted?

Comment: Have you tried  to escape '-' ? try "\-server", maybe that will work, I am just guessing here.

Comment: When I use "\-server" its interpeted as `Failed to stop \-server.service: Unit \-server.service not loaded.`

Comment: Try single quotes. E.g., sudo systemctl stop '-server'

Comment: I have tried to use both single and double quotes. Both's output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution would be to tell `systemctl` to treat the service name as a non-argument using `--`:

```sh
$ systemd-run --user --unit="-myservice" /bin/sleep infinity
$ systemctl --user is-active -- -myservice.service
active
$ systemctl --user stop -- -myservice.service
$ systemctl --user is-active -- -myservice.service
inactive
```